# Jesus subject to Father

Tags: 1-corinthians

1 Corinthians 15:27-28, King James Version

> For he hath put all things under his feet. But when he saith all things are put under him, it is manifest that he is excepted which did put all things under him. And when all things shall be subdued unto him, then shall the Son also himself be subject unto him that put all things under him, that God may be all in all.

Is this saying that Jesus will be subject to God the Father who put all things in subjection to the Son? Is this subjection of the Son to magnify the Father alone so "God may be as all in all"?

Comment: *Wouldn't all things be under him already, if he was God?* - Are you saying that all things are under God? Because, in that case, there would be no sin, or death, or illness, or any type of physical or spiritual degeneration.

Comment: I guess so... yes now we do not see all things under his feet your right.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trap in this question that goes like this.  The Christian faith is fiercely monotheistic - ONE God.  Now, for those that insist that Jesus is not God but just God's Son have to decide one more matter:

If Jesus is God's Son, and not God (as is the Father), then Jesus is either not God and cannot be worshipped, or, if He is God then a lesser God and thus there are two Gods.  The latter would amount to ditheism.

Historically, it was this realisation that lead directly to the Doctrine of the Trinity - three co-equal persons composing ONE God.  This is the only conclusion that is consistent will ALL the NT data, namely that, Jesus is regularly called God (John 1:1, John 1:18, John 5:17, 18, John 20:28, Rom 9:5, “…Messiah, who is God over all, forever praised! Amen”, Phil 2:5-8, “…Jesus Christ: who, being in very nature God…”, Titus 2:13, “…our great God and Saviour, Jesus Christ.”, Heb 1:8, “About the Son he says, ‘Your throne, O God, will last forever’”, 2 Peter 1:1, “…righteousness of our God and Saviour, Jesus Christ.”, Isa 9:6) and the NT also calls Jesus YHWH (eg, compare Deut 4:35, 6:4; Isa 44:6, 45:5, 6 with Matt 1:22, 23; John 1:1, 18 20:28, OR, compare Isa 44:24, 45:18 with John 1:3, Col 1:16, 17, OR, compare Isa 43:3,11, 45:17,21 with Matt 1:21; Acts 4:12; 2 Tim 1:10; Tit 2:13; 2 Pet 1:1, 11, etc, etc).

Thus, the best answer to the question is found in Phil 2:5-8 where Jesus' absolute equality with the Father is declared but Jesus voluntarily took humanity and became subject to the Father as an example of the lives we should live in complete subjection to God.  That is, Jesus was our example in all things 1 John 2:6 (plus many more).

Comment: Jesus himself says that that the word of God calls others "gods" John 10:34-35. The strict monotheism of modern Christians is not biblically consistent. There is a whole council of gods whom God calls His sons. See Psalms 82. There is however only one true God. The rest are images of Him kinda like there is only one Father, and other fathers only image what He creates through their procreation.

Answer (score 1):

1 Cor 15:27-28

> For "He has put in subjection all things under his feet." But when it may be said that all things have been put in subjection, it is evident that the One having put in subjection all things to him is excepted. BLB

> For “God has put everything under His feet.” Now when it says that everything has been put under him, this clearly does not include the One who put everything under him. BSB

**Is this saying that Jesus will be subject to God the Father who put all things in subjection to the Son?**

That much would be obvious from the verse itself.

- One (God) is doing the organising here.
- God is making Jesus 2nd in charge under Him.
- Jesus is therefore *subject* to God as God is clearly over all - incl. Jesus.

We might investigate this naturally revealing truth to see if other texts agree and provide an extra dimension or understanding. This arrangement God has decreed, though Paul, is after the resurrection process has been completed.

> ...Christ the firstfruit, then those of Christ at his coming, then the end, when he shall hand over the kingdom to the God and Father, when he shall have annulled all dominion, and all authority and power. 1 Cor 15:24

This is after the second death (Rev 20) and the power of all evil has been defeated and all humanity has either been granted eternal life or have suffered the second death and permanently erased from existence.

Jesus has always been under authority and has been given his authority by God.

> Then Jesus came to them and said, "All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me. Matt 28:18

> And God put everything under his feet and made him head over everything for the church Eph 1:22

> (God) putting everything in subjection under his feet. Now in putting everything in subjection to him, He (God) left nothing outside his control. At present, we do not yet see everything in subjection to him. Heb 2:8

So Paul continues explaining how Jesus was subjected to a period of proving before this authority granted him was fully realised. Jesus, as the son of God, had to mature before receiving his inheritance. Heb 1:2

> we see him who for a little while was made lower than the angels v9

> For it was fitting that He, for whom and by whom all things exist, in bringing many sons to glory, should make the founder (Jesus) of their salvation perfect through suffering.v10

This subjection is also recognised in other ways.

- I am going to the Father, because the Father is greater than I. John 14:28

> Therefore the Jews sought the more to kill him, because he not only had broken the Sabbath, but said also that God was his Father, making himself equal with God. John 5:18

We have two options here;

1. Believe Jesus - who both in the flesh and the exalted, immortal life, he is subject to God. All that he has is granted from God, and he is appointed heir to all God's creation Heb 1:2
2. Believe the Jews who clearly didn't understand anything that Jesus was doing - they thought he had a demon! John 8:52, 48

The choice *seems* very obvious. Go with Jesus, or go with the arrogant, prideful and desperate Jews who despised Jesus words and his bringing prophecy true before their closed eyes and minds. Strangely, many still want to side with the Jews and claim their desperate shouts of 'blasphemy' (John 10) confirm Jesus is God and not subject to God as scripture abundantly shows.

**Is this subjection of the Son to magnify the Father alone so "God may be as all in all"?**

Everything Jesus does is to glorify the Father and his God.

> Jesus says, “Now the Son of Man has been glorified, and God has been glorified in him. 32If God is glorified in him, God also will glorify him in Himself, and will glorify him immediately. John 3:31